# What styles can be effected by pinch zoom(scaling)

Tags: javascript, css, pinchzoom

I have a css issue that only pops up when pinch zoom (scaling, not actual zoom with ctrl + '+') is used. This can be seen in a mac trackpad or any pinch zoom enabled tablet.

What styles can be effected by pinch zoom? I thought zoom didn't effect the width and positional settings in the window, only the size of the viewport crop shown to the user.

Comment: My understanding is that `zoom` is diiferent to *scaling* which is what pinch-zoom does. In any case, zoom is handled differently by each browser I believe.

Comment: Some mobile browsers also handle pinch zoom on mobile sites differently from pinch zoom on desktop sites.

Comment: Most of the time, it doesn't affect the styles at all. Your mobile browser basically takes a "screenshot" of the website then scales that screenshot larger or smaller when zooming.